# Where do I find access logs for file stored in S3

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We just wanted to know, if someone added or deleted file in an particular bucket.

Is there a place we can look at ?
* I dont want a programmatic interface, just to look at manually.  *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable logging on a specific bucket.  Once you do Amazon will start saving logs in another bucket (usually something like "bucket-name-logging" though it is definable once you set it up so it can have any name)  [Here is a link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html) to parsing the format.  There will be one key for each access event (each GET, PUT, DELETE etc), so you may want to look into a programmatic way of reading them like [Sawmill](http://www.sawmill.net/formats/amazon_s3.html).

Comment: 1. How frequently does it update the logs ?  Can we configure the frequency with which it gets updated ?

Comment: I haven't found a direct answer to this but looking at some of our logs it looks like there is some grouping when events take place really close to each (within a second of each other).  Again without hard documentation, this is just anecdotal